# How to delete rows from Replicated&Distributed tables on Clickhouse?

Tags: database, replication, delete-row, clickhouse

I have a table which is a distributed table over replicated tables in Clickhouse.

Although I have tried different things I can not delete any rows from the table. What should I do?

Delete queries I have tried.

```
delete from distributed_table where userid = 22387715
```

```
ALTER TABLE distributed_table on cluster cluster_name DELETE WHERE userid = 22387715
```

Comment: How are you confirming that the rows have or have not been deleted?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using the tag. The `distribution` tag is for statistical distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looked into this a little further. You can do the DELETE on the table, but you can't send the DELETE command to the distributed_table. You can send the DELETE command to the underlying data table however:

```
ALTER TABLE underlying_data_table ON CLUSTER cluster_name DELETE
WHERE userid = 22387715;
```

Hope this helps, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Without any table definitions or details, my guess is that the rows are marked for deletion (in your lightweight delete above) but your parts haven't merged yet. A `DELETE` command creates a mutation, which happens "eventually", not immediately.

Rows are not actually deleted until the parts merge. Check the `system.mutations` table and see if your mutation has completed yet.

Comment: When I run lightweight delete I get  'DELETE query is not supported for table' error. And system.mutations table is empty.

Comment: 1. Lightweight deletes are relatively new, so make sure they exist for your version of ClickHouse
2. They only work on MergeTree-type tables

Answer (score 0):

I think deleting a certain row on distributed tables is not allowed. When I partitioned my table and dropped the partition it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have partitioned your data and the target data is located in one specific partition, you can delete it using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name [ON CLUSTER cluster] DROP PARTITION|PART partition_expr
```

[for more details click here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/partition)